# How to replace parameters with 2 strings

Tags: java

The method accepts two strings s1,s2 as parameters and returns the string in the object that is triggered when each instance of string s1 is replaced by s2. otherwise, it will do nothing

for example :

if we have string:**"abcdecc"** , with parameters **s1="cc"** and **s2="fff"** 
then the method will return string as : **"abcdefff"** 
replaced s1 with s2

Comment: Can we see the method?

Comment: There is a method in the String class which does exactly this. What is the problem with that one?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: just `"abcdecc".replace(s1, s2)`

Answer (score 3):

If you have (or can include) Apache Commons library in your project, then I recommend using [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

```
String result = StringUtils.replace("abcdecc", "cc", "fff");
```

You can use String.replace() as well but it uses Regex, so in terms of performance StringUtils.replace() is better.

Comment: Just did a quick test:

    _Duration of String.replace() for 100_000_000 calls: **PT35.735S**_

    _Duration of StringUtils.replace() for 100_000_000 calls: **PT7.645S**_

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this as your method:

```
String replace_method(String s, String s1, String s2){    
   return s.replace(s1, s2);    
}
```